# What are the differences between ships in Battlefront (x-wing, a-wing, tie, tie interceptor)

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

What are the differences between ships in Battlefront?

The tie interceptor seems faster than the tie fighter, but also seems to die from less direct hits. The A-wing also seems to be a smaller, quicker version of the X-wing that dies faster.

Is there any documentation or user tests that determine the differences between star fighters in Star Wars Battlefront?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice [writeup on primagames](http://www.primagames.com/games/star-wars-battlefront/tips/star-wars-battlefront-vehicle-guide-x-wing-tie-fighter) that explains the difference:

**A-Wing**

One of the more dependable vehicles you'll find in Fighter Squadron, Walker Assault or Supremacy, the A-Wing can deliver a great deal of damage, while at the same time generating a temporary shield to protect from damage.

Locking on to enemies with the A-Wing is a snap by holding down the left trigger. From there, you can fire away with your blasters (if they're not overheated) and shoot concussion missiles once they lock on. Both of these do significant damage, but make sure you protect your backside, as an enemy is likely to lock onto you.

Evasive maneuvers can make all the difference as you can barrel roll or execute a 180-degree turn to get out of harm's way, and perhaps even get the jump on your opponents. You can also distribute your speed by pressing either up to shift the power to your engines, or down if you want to cycle to your weapons.

**X-Wing**

The X-Wing is similar to the A-Wing in terms of the weapons provided, including shield and lock-on proton torpedoes, but it has a better firing range thanks to its foils, and a little better maneuverability on tight turns.

Again, the lock-on and evasive techniques remain in place as they did before, so be sure to get every fighter you can, while at the same time protecting your own hide. The same energy distribution system is in play, so whether you need speed or firing capability, you can switch to both with relative ease.

**TIE Fighter**

The Dark Side is strong with this vehicle, as TIE Fighters can lock onto enemies as well, firing lasers and the Ion Cannon to deliver a devastating blow. For good measure, you can also use a speed boost if you feel like rushing into battle or getting away from a particularly crafty enemy.

As with the Rebel vehicles, TIE Fighters also have energy distribution, so you can balance what kind of firepower or speed you need with your vehicle with simple nudges.

One more thing – the TIE Fighters have great maneuverability in the air, but can take less damage than X-Wings. Keep this in mind the next time you get into a dogfight.

**TIE Interceptor**

Finally, the TIE Interceptor is a slightly more advanced version of the TIE Fighter, with most of the same abilities and handling we've come to expect. If you prefer to pilot something to what Darth Vader handled in the first movie, this is the best way to go.

You'll want to make proper use of its energy distribution and keep an eye on your six in case you need to do a quick barrel roll or 180 spin. Remember, it’s just as vulnerable as the TIE Fighter, so you'll want to whirl around and get back at your enemies with gunfire as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The x-wing is slower, with more health but deals less damage and has a faster DPS compared to,

the a-wing which is faster but has less health, deals more damage but has a slower DPS

This is the same with the TIE fighter and TIE interceptor

with the TIE fighter which is slower, with more health but deals less damage and has a faster DPS compared to,

the TIE interceptor which is faster but has less health, deals more damage but has a slower DPS

Comment: Seems pretty solid. I agree with this answer.

Comment: Why is this downvoted when I done my own user test and this is the results along with watching others gameplay and thanks @TrentonJames

Comment: Probably because you have no source for your information other than personal experience. I think he is looking for something with solid proof. Maybe if you could show a video or screenshot of gameplay?

Comment: You should not say `faster dps`, it doesn't make any sense. DPS (damage per second) is already timed, it can't be faster or slower. It can be higher or lower. You might be referring to rate of fire.

Comment: Though some of these assertions match what I also believe, there is no evidence to support them other than "it feels like this when I play". Which isn't a very conclusive answer. I have not downvoted it, but this answer in its' current state would not be accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Faster DPS is an odd phrasing, but it makes perfect sense. A higher DPS would result in more damage being done faster. Alternatively, it would result in the thing you are shooting dying faster.