# What are the different relative speeds of each flying craft?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

In this question: [What are the differences between ships in Battlefront (x-wing, a-wing, tie, tie interceptor)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246090/3128) the general characteristics of the different flying craft are discussed but speed is only vaguely mentioned.
[image: A-wing]
I used to think that each craft had a different speed, but I recently noticed a counter example. I was able to stay behind an air speeder with a tie fighter for quite a while. Which leads me to believe that all the flying craft generally move at about the same speed.

Do all flying craft fly at the same speed, except when using a speed boost?

If not, what's the order of craft from fastest to slowest?

Comment: I can't confirm the numbers in Battlefront, but based on my memory of other SW games I've played, the A-Wing and Interceptor should be the fastest, followed by the Tie Fighter, then the X-Wing, then the Air Speeder.

Answer (score 2):

I think from fastest to slowest it's: The falcon, a-wing, tie interceptor and tie fighter(beats x-wing because of speed boost) then the x-wing, then slave one, and then the airspeeder.

i think that the tie interceptor is faster than the tie fighter, and without the speed boost the tie fighter would be about equal with the x-wing.

Comment: If you can add official date or test date please go ahead ! =)

Comment: I can't this is the result of my own observations while playing way too much fighter squadron, when I had just started playing I also looked for different speeds, but was unable to find any official documentation.